# What's wrong in this code? It doesn't insert row in the table

Tags: php, sql

It doesn't insert row in the table.

```
/*add to group*/
if($edu_school=="I.T"){
    $group_id = $_POST["3"];
    $db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO groups_members (group_id, user_id) VALUES (%s,%s)" )) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is you set value?!

Try like this

```
if($edu_school=="I.T"){
    $group_id = (string)$_POST["3"];
    $query=sprintf("INSERT INTO groups_members (group_id, user_id) VALUES (%s,%s)",$group_id,"1" );
     $db->query($query) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The values for both string placeholders are missing. See [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for documentation.

**Side note**: Please be aware that with this method your code will still be vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).